# ¿Cómo mapear Usando Dapper en C# con multiobjetos?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, postgresql, dapper

Buenas comunidad estoy haciendo una API y para consultas sin JOIN logro recuperar datos, pero cuando traté de realizar búsquedas de select que hace JOINS con otras tablas para completar datos en Objetos que contienen otros objetos empiezo a tener este problema.
Por ej. La clase Cliente que contiene a la clase Persona.

Desde ya gracias por cualquier aporte! Saludos.

Instalé Dapper, y al probar la request obtengo el siguiente error:

***"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApiTalleres.Models.Cliente]' to type 'WebApiTalleres.Models.Cliente'."***

Les cuento un poco de la arquitectura del proyecto.

- C# VS.Net Core 3.1
- Base de datos Postgresql 14.
- Un proyecto en la solución que posee todos los objetos que son los Models.
- Un Proyecto con la conexión a base de datos.
- Un Proyecto con los controladores.

**Modelo de Cliente:**

```
public partial class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }       
    public Persona Persona { get; set; }
    public int? TallerId { get; set; }
}
```

**Modelo de Persona:**

```
public partial class Persona
{     
    public int PersonaId { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FecNacimiento { get; set; }
    public int? IdLocalidad { get; set; }
    public string Barrio { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public short? NroDireccion { get; set; }
    public string Dpto { get; set; }
    public int? Piso { get; set; }
    public string Telcelular { get; set; }
    public string Telfijo { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int? IdTipoIdentificador { get; set; }
    public int? NroIdentificacion { get; set; }
    public string TipoPersona { get; set; }
    public int? IdGenero { get; set; }
    public string Ocupacion { get; set; }
    public int? IdEstadoCivil { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaAlta { get; set; }
    public string UsrAlta { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaBaja { get; set; }
    public string UsrBaja { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaMod { get; set; }
    public string UsrMod { get; set; }        
}

    public async Task<Cliente> find(int id)
    {          
        var sql_query = @" select   a.*,
                                    b.* 
                           from public.""clientes"" as a 
                            inner join
                            public.""personas"" as b
                            on(a.personaid = b.personaid)
                            where b.personasid = @Id";

        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();

        parameters.Add("Id", id, DbType.Int32);

        using (var connection = dbConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();

            Cliente oCliente = (Cliente) await connection.QueryAsync<Cliente, Persona, Cliente>(
                    sql_query,
                    (cliente, persona) =>
                    {
                        cliente.Persona = persona;
                        return cliente;
                    },
                    splitOn: "personaid")           
                ;

            return  oCliente;
        }
    }
```

**Controlador de Cliente**.

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCliente(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var cliente = await _clienteDao.find(id);
            if (cliente == null)
                return NotFound();
            return Ok(cliente);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log error
            return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: El error te está diciendo que intentas asignar a una variable de tipo `..Cliente`  una **Lista** de `..Cliente`. No parece tener que ver con que el objeto sea complejo. Supongo que el problema está aqui: `(Cliente) await connection.QueryAsync..`. `QueryAsync` te va a devolver una lista, no un objeto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partiendo de la base que CLiente / Persona por la estructura de datos parecen tener una relacion 1 a 1 y no 1 a N:

Simplemente necesitas hacer esto:

```cs
using (var connection = dbConnection()) {
            connection.Open();

            List<Cliente> oCliente = await connection.QueryAsync<Cliente, Persona, Cliente>(
                    sql_query,
                    (cliente, persona) => {
                        cliente.Persona = persona;
                        return cliente;
                    },
                    splitOn: "personaid");

            return  oCliente; //<--Aqui hay un List<>
}
```